# How to make a SVG image become blurred in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I want to use a svg with 2 blurred corners to have a gradient background in react native, but the issue is those blurred corners become 2 circle. Any solutions?. Here is the images:

[image: The one that I want]

[image: The output]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient), instead of having 2 SVGs in the corners of the component.
You can specify which colors and where the gradient starts and ends on both X and Y axises.

But if you are determined to use them, I recommend using [react-native-blur](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur) and adjusting the styling of the component according to your needs